# Cheerio npm package abit slow

Tags: node.js, cheerio

Am using [cheerio](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheerio) to manipulate html, but the `cheerio.load(htmlcontent)`took *1916 milliseconds*. Is it normal to be this slow or does it depend with the size of the html because the html has a base64 image inside and total size about `800kb` to be exact am using html of [this article](https://jamesclear.com/successful-people-start-before-they-feel-ready) as an example. If its not, can anyone suggest a better package, because e.g. if this is just one, how long is processing ten such contents going to take, i want something abit more efficient

Comment: If you expect people to suggest alternative solutions, you should explain your problem first. As far as I know, cheerio is the fastest server-side jQuery port available on npm. But I don't know whether you actually need jQuery API or not.

Comment: @LeonidBeschastny i actually wanted to know if there was a faster library, it doesn't matter which kind of API i could work with any

Comment: Try [whacko](https://github.com/inikulin/whacko), it's a fork with a faster parser.

Comment: The package is no longer maintained @pguardiario

Comment: It's just a fork that uses a different parser. There's nothing to maintain.